# pde with linear coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

Is there a general theory for linear, 2nd-order PDE in two dimension, when all coefficients are linear functions of the two variables?

If not, how would you proceed with an equation like

$$ x f_{xx} + (k_1+k_2 x)  f_x + ( k_3 + k_4 x +k_5 y ) f_y + k_6  f = 0$$

Thank you.

Comment: A power series solution should work, though it might be messy.

Comment: Probably there's no hope for a reasonable answer for generic parameter values. Even in the special case that $k_3 = k_4 = k_5 = 0$, where there's no dependence on $y$ and the equation is essentially an ODE, the general solution depends on confluent hypergeometric functions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function